# Passing indexpath to performsequewithidentifier from uitablerowaction button

Tags: ios, xcode, segue

Here is my `delegate` method:

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
UITableViewRowAction *button = [
                                UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"More" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AreaDescriptionSegue" sender:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"More button tapped");
}
                                ];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; //arbitrary color
return @[button]; //array with all the buttons you want. 1,2,3, etc...
}
```

And here is my `prepareforsegue`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AreaDescriptionSegue"]) {
    NSLog(@"segue from Areas screen");
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [self.listTableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    AreaDescriptionController *vc = (AreaDescriptionController*)[segue destinationViewController];
    vc.area = _feedItems[newIndexPath.row];

}
}
```

The object is passed to the `destinationViewController` but it is always the first object item and not at the correct `indexPath`.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: may be indexpath is taking your block local indexpath.try to rename that block indexpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the indexPath as the sender (in performSegue), so there's no need to get the indexPath with this line (in fact it won't work since "sender" is not a cell),

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [self.listTableView indexPathForCell:sender]
```

You should do this,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSIndexPath *)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AreaDescriptionSegue"]) {
        NSLog(@"segue from Areas screen");
        AreaDescriptionController *vc = (AreaDescriptionController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.area = _feedItems[sender.row];

    }
}
```

The reason you always got the first row, is that newIndexPath will be nil, and newIndexPath.row evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 0):

In this line,

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AreaDescriptionSegue" sender:indexPath];
```

you are already sending the index path. Then,

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [self.listTableView indexPathForCell:sender];
```

you are taking the sender as Cell. Actually the sender is indexPath. You should directly use the sender as indexPath.